# add id_parent to nested tree array in javascript or typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a nested `array` of `tree type`, each item has an `id`, I would like to add to the `children` the `id_parent` that would be the `id` of its `ancestor array`

```
let data =  [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "nombre": "TITULO A",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "nombre": "SUB TITULO A",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "3",
                                "nombre": "ITEM A",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "4",
                                        "nombre": "SUB ITEM A",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "id": "5",
                                                "nombre": "DETALLE ITEM A",
                                                "children": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                 "id": "6",
                                                "nombre": "DETALLE ITEM A2",
                                                "children": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "7",
                "nombre": "TITULO B",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "8",
                        "nombre": "SUB TITULO B",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "9",
                                "nombre": "ITEM B",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "10",
                                        "nombre": "SUB ITEM B",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "11",
                                        "nombre": "SUB ITEM B2",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "12",
                                        "nombre": "SUB ITEM B3",
                                        "children": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "13",
                                "nombre": "ITEM B2",
                                "children": []
                           }                          
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

expected result

```
 let result =  [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                     "id_parent": null,
                    "nombre": "TITULO A",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "id_parent": "1",
                            "nombre": "SUB TITULO A",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": "3",
                                    "id_parent": "2",
                                    "nombre": "ITEM A",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using a recursive `function`, which iterates if `children` has `items`.

```
addParent(data){
  let parent = null;
  Object.keys(data).forEach(x => {
     this.setParent(data[x], parent);
  });
}
        
setParent(node, parent){
  node.id_parent = parent;
  node.children.forEach(x => {
       this.setParent(x, node.id);
  });
}
```